# bundle install using wrong ruby with rvm when building native extension?

Tags: ruby, rvm, bundler

I'm using `bundle install` to install `rest-client`. It's failing with the following:

```
$ bundle
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..........
Fetching version metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Resolving dependencies...
Installing unf_ext 0.0.7.4 with native extensions

Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /home/roger/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4@junk-drawer/gems/unf_ext-0.0.7.4/ext/unf_ext
/usr/bin/ruby2.3 -r ./siteconf20180115-9722-1iow75n.rb extconf.rb
mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at /usr/lib/ruby/include/ruby.h

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /home/roger/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4@junk-drawer/gems/unf_ext-0.0.7.4 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/roger/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4@junk-drawer/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.3.0/unf_ext-0.0.7.4/gem_make.out
Installing mime-types-data 3.2016.0521
Installing netrc 0.11.0
Using bundler 1.11.2
An error occurred while installing unf_ext (0.0.7.4), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install unf_ext -v '0.0.7.4'` succeeds before bundling.
```

I'm using rvm, which appears to be working correctly, if I'm reading the output from `rvm info` right.

`which ruby` reports `/home/roger/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.4/bin/ruby`, which looks right.

I found [Install ruby headers with rvm](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11575231/8446), but I *have* Ruby headers in (apparently) the correct place:

```
$ ruby -rmkmf -e 'print RbConfig::CONFIG["rubyhdrdir"]'
/home/roger/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.4/include/ruby-2.3.0
$ ls /home/roger/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.4/include/ruby-2.3.0
ruby/  ruby.h  x86_64-linux/
```

In the output from `bundle`, I see `/usr/bin/ruby2.3`, which looks suspicious.

**It's looking in the wrong place for Ruby header files. How do I get it to use the RVM-installed ones?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using the wrong `bundle`.

```
$ which bundle
/usr/bin/bundle
```

Either the one included in Ubuntu 16.04 is old, or using the system-installed bundler doesn't work with rvm-installed Ruby.

```
$ gem install bundler
Fetching: bundler-1.16.1.gem (100%)
...
1 gem installed
$ which bundle
/home/roger/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4@junk-drawer/bin/bundle
```

That looks better.

```
$ bundle
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.........
Resolving dependencies...
Using bundler 1.16.1
...
Bundle complete! 1 Gemfile dependency, 9 gems now installed.
Use `bundle info [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.
```

Lesson learned: **when using rvm, remember to `gem install bundler` as well.**